# Insert geometry values in mysql using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, point

I am using https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql module with node.js.

Mysql table has a field of type `POINT`. The module requires to send array of arrays to insert bulk records. But It doesn't seem to have option to specify data type.

So naturally, the following gets enclosed in quotes

```
var loc = "GeomFromText('POINT(" + lat + "," + lon + ")')";
```

Has anybody tried this? How can I convince the query builder to treat this as an sql function?

Or do I have to make my own query builder?

Comment: Don't concatenate data into the query like this.  Placeholders will work in MySQL functions just like they will anywhere else.  In any case, there is no problem with quotes.  Can you show an example of what query you're actually trying to run?

Comment: You mean parameterized query? Could you guide how to do that with this module?

Comment: I don't have the documentation handy, but if I remember correctly, just plug in question marks `?` for the variables, and then pass an array to fill them as the second parameter to the query function call.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try. And post the query it generates.

Comment: Inserting one record with that method is fine, but bulk insert fails, m trying to find out what's wrong by looking at module source. Any inputs?

Comment: I'm not sure... I haven't done a bulk insert with that module before.  Sorry I can't be of more help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/pull/877) from [kevinhikaruevans](https://github.com/kevinhikaruevans) that does it. You can do something like that to convert objects to points:

```
if (typeof val === 'object') {
    if(val.hasOwnProperty('lat') && val.hasOwnProperty('long')) {
        return 'POINT(' + [val.lat, val.long].map(parseFloat).join(',') + ')';
    }
}
```

Supposing you have a table `mytable` with only the field `point` of type `POINT`, you would insert them like this:

```
var points = [
    [{ lat: 1, long: 4}],
    [{ lat: 23, long: -8.345}]
];
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO mytable(point) VALUES ?', [points], your_callback_func);
console.log("Query: " + query.sql);
```

This will generate a query similar to:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(point)
VALUES (POINT(1,4)), (POINT(23,-8.345))
```

This would convert any object with both `lat` and `long` fields to a MySQL point. If this is not an intended behavior, you could create a `Point` class and use it instead of plain objects, and in `lib/protocol/SqlString.js` check if the value is an instance of `Point`.

Answer (score 3):

Try constructing a query to handle `POINT()` and batch where `site` is an object with properties and values shown below. This approach works for me.

```
pool.query('INSERT INTO table SET geometryField = POINT(?,?), ?',[coords.lat,coords.lng,site], function(err, response) {

{ sitename: 'A Site',
  customer: 'A Customer',
  country: 'AL',
  timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  address1: '123 My Street',
  city: 'MyCity',
  state: 'WA',
  postalcode: '98110'}
```